# Как ОС может работать с большим объемом ОЗУ чем процессор?

Tags: ос, процессор

Процессор х64 поддерживает 128(2^64) ГБ ОЗУ, однако, если верить [этому](https://answers.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/forum/windows_10-win_upgrade/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB/eae78260-676d-4f6e-ab65-d765f4e2b39a?auth=1) ресурсу, то `Windows 10 PRO` может видеть и работать с 512 ГБ озу.

Как это работает? В ОС на ходу подменяются адресные пространства, создавая эмуляцию работы с большим ОЗУ?

Если это так, то эффективен ли этот подход? С виду, он похож на виртуализацию, которая используется в файлах подкачки.

Если мне не изменяет память, то слышал, что под `DOS'ом` в свое время Microsoft такую же фишку делала на старых процессорах с помощью каких-то драйверов.

Comment: Может каким либо способом ее фрагментирует? Своеобразный пейджинг на пространствах ?

Comment: 2^64 это не 128...

Comment: 2^32 это 4 Гб памяти.
2^64 это 16 млн терабайт памяти.
Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос

Comment: @nick_gabpe, x64 использует 48-разрядную шину адреса, так что 2^48=256ТБ. Но согласен, это гораздо больше чем 128ГБ.

Comment: @Anamnian, ^^^^

Comment: Хм... видать меня смутило, что на некоторых процессорах в спецификации прописан максимальный объём поддерживаемой памяти.

Answer (score 0):

Это называется страничная организация памяти и свопинг. В ОЗУ в каждый момент времени лежит только часть задачи. Остальное лежит на диске в файле свопинга. Когда происходит обращение к странице памяти, которой сейчас нету в ОЗУ, то ОС подкачивает из файла свопинга недостающие страницы а старые выгружает на диск. Так что создается впечатление, что каждая задача имеет гораздо больше ОЗУ, чем даже установлено в системе.

Если запустить много задач, то все время будет уходить на свопинг, диск будет колотить а система будет тормозить.